CMake Tools runs build before running ctest, but I don't want it to / think it doesn't need to
cmake.buildBeforeRun is not working as expected.
I have CMake project with a custom CMake Preset for different builds, Our Unit test are doctest based which we add in ctest using  "doctest_discover_tests".I'm encountering unnecessary builds before running tests in the Testing Explorer in my VS Code.
I have disabled cmake.buildBeforeRun in settings.json but it still configures and builds before each test run.
All files are unchanged. How can I prevent this redundant build step?
setting.json:
{
   "cmake.ctest.testExplorerIntegrationEnabled": true,
   "cmake.buildBeforeRun": false
}

Expectation :
{
  "cmake.buildBeforeRun": false
}

Should prevent redundant build step whenever i run test from testing explorer.


cmake.buildBeforeRun is not working as expected

Then you should read the docs. The docs state:

If true, build the launch/debug target before running the target.

This is accurate. At least if you're using Presets (I don't use Kits, so I don't know what happens with that). Selecting a test preset is a separate thing from selecting a Debug/Launch target.


How can I prevent this redundant build step?

I'm going to do something I don't do often and say I think you should just accept this. It really shouldn't matter as long as your buildsystem is doing its job (avoiding rebuilding anything that isn't dirty or dependent (directly or transitively) on anything that is dirty). I'd expect this behaviour to be a useful default, and if you want to not test changes to sources that you've saved and just test whatever targets were last built... I mean- sure maybe that's a fair use-case, but you can look into git worktrees as a workaround.
Anyhow, from my quick reading of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/8ed18b224ad14799992465010a7e5ab46a6fa16a/src/ctest.ts#L33, it's currently hardcoded to happen by CMake Tools, interestingly- regardless of, and I think without using ctest flags like --build-and-test.
If you want a different behaviour, you should give a thumbs up to Do not automatically build before running CTest #2933.
